# Relation (if any) between the Representer theorem and Bayes’ formula

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

Im studying for a Advance Machine Learning Exam, and I came across this question:

- What is the relation (if any) between the Representer theorem and Bayes’ formula? Is one more general than the other?

I know both of them, but I do not know if there is any direct relation between them. Someone could help?